# Sum values in column based on values in other column and append to df - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, append

I have a df that looks like this:
[df here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVIW8.png)

The column Count gives values that are either 0 or stretches of higher numbers separated by zeros e.g. 0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0.

I would like to sum the values of the column "angle_1frame_abs" for each stretch and add it as new column to the df e.g.

Count: 0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,...

angle_1frame_abs: 2,1,3,4,2,2,2,3,4,3,...

new column: 10,10,10,10,16,16,16,16,16,16,...

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems what you need is to divide your df into segments with the same consecutive value of `Count`, and sum over the `angle_1frame_abs` within each segment, and copy the sum of each segment to each row of the segment.

In your case we cannot use `Count` as the key for `groupby`, so we need a new one:

```
new_key = (df['Count'].diff().abs() > 0).cumsum()
```

Using the new key, we can do the sum:

```
the_sum = df.groupby( new_key )['angle_1frame_abs'].sum()
```

And copy the summation results back to the table by the new key

```
df['NewColumn'] = new_key.map(the_sum)
```

Note that we use `diff()` to find out the boundary of segments, and used `abs() > 0` to convert boundary values to `True/False` or `1/0`, then use `cumsum` to get the new key by leveraging the fact that the cumsum doesn't change outside the boundary (i.e. within the segment).

I tested my code using the following fake data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Count': [2,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,1], 
    'angle_1frame_abs': [np.nan,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,2,2,2,2],
})
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. When using your practise df this also worked for me but for some reason it does not work with my "real" df :(

Comment: can you pick a part of the dataframe that would fail, and share the outcome of `print(sub_dataframe.to_dict('list'))`

Comment: Oh thank you, I was struggling showing the data here: {'new_key': [12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14], 'Count': [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0], 'angle_1frame_abs': [2.5643166946364895, 1.7200119466735702, 1.165831264332026, 2.025448676170986, 1.102366607595272, 2.3605660470439824, 1.5685525010916657, 0.2824668441553374, 1.4750896187081886, 0.23109066719590768], 'angle_1frame_abs_sum': [32.83937186139538, 5.537399834039681, 289.31358278892174, 1.742769904420554, 1.7041313669329061, 62.03673079625949, 5.9045798835381476, 369.5048292742004, 14.801701703482602, 23.780548498600858]}

Comment: Here also the first 10 rows: {'new_key': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'Count': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'angle_1frame_abs': [nan, 1.0156886173738409, 1.215073266136775, 2.3217253891926046, 3.0756092850689076, 0.06261397002469785, 0.8517862119013955, 2.438620187141711, 2.3123978133485408, 0.759762754875774], 'angle_1frame_abs_sum': [115.51767479853574, 9.326831047698985, 122.23974341516696, 3.2407187695004156, 18.323888655577065, 7.142841737183863, 63.99426420721478, 3.131013254285691, 44.33577437301901, 4.818140703391943]}

Comment: my code can work on your data provided here :/

Comment: this works. `df = pd.DataFrame({'Count': [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0], 'angle_1frame_abs': [2.5643166946364895, 1.7200119466735702, 1.165831264332026, 2.025448676170986, 1.102366607595272, 2.3605660470439824, 1.5685525010916657, 0.2824668441553374, 1.4750896187081886, 0.23109066719590768]})`

Comment: Hey, if you share the data from the first row up to the block of data you shared in comment #3, how many rows are there in total?

Comment: Also, from the data you shared here, you have a new column called `new_key` that does not exist in my code. So I suppose you have made some changes to my code. If you really just apply my code on your "real" df, would it also fail?

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry, there was something I did not copy exactly as I thought I knew what I was doing but apparently not - thank you a lot!!

Comment: It's fine. I'm glad to hear it works. :)